# Store time in database

Tags: php, timezone

Which is the best way to store data which come from the entire world?
I was thinking, for instance, to store the time() without timezone and then convert it every time.

Could be right? Is there a method to detect timezone of a request?

Comment: Question is unclear.. Please give some more explanations and put some code you had tried still

Comment: TIMESTAMP is good and you can adapt it to any timezone. But "best" way to store data related to your needs only.

Comment: I mean, I want that people who lives in UK (example) insert a record and the time of its is related to their timezone.

Comment: You haven't specified the db, but read this about timestamps and UTC, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can save a *Unix Timestamp* in your database.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

`Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).`

So every people have the same timestamp format without a timezone.

Otherwise you have to store a *Datetime* field and the Timezone and calculate the correct value.